# Return the value of the first expression in Bison

Tags: c, parsing, recursion, bison, flex-lexer

I am writing a parser in Bison and flex to parse a "self-made" language. The language contains certain constant expressions of the type:

```
[OPERATOR, OPERAND1, OPERAND2]
```

Where an operand can be either a string, integer, real, or another operator expression giving us something like

```
[OPERATOR, [OPERATOR, OPERAND1, OPERAND2], OPERAND2]
```

or `[OPERATOR, Int1, Int2]` etc.

The issue is I want to return on the result of the main expression that calls the other expressions as well. I have made a rule titled as `fulloperation` to try to deal with this but it only works if the operation expression is followed by another statement (expression is a type of statement). These are my grammar rules and you can find my attempt at recursive return under the `fulloperation` rule (Note the program starts and ends between a left and right square bracket):

```
%union{
IntNode intnode;
RealNode realnode;
StrNode strnode;
ExprNode * exprNodePtr;
int linenum;
}

%token <linenum> tADD 
%token <linenum> tSUB 
%token <linenum> tMUL 
%token <linenum> tDIV 
%token <strnode> tSTRING 
%token <intnode> tNUMI
%token <realnode> tNUMR 
%token tPRINT tGET tSET tFUNCTION tRETURN tIDENT tEQUALITY tIF tGT tLT tGEQ tLEQ tINC tDEC 

%type <exprNodePtr> operation;
%type <exprNodePtr> expr;
%type <exprNodePtr> fulloperation;
%start prog 

%%
prog:       '[' stmtlst ']' ;
;

stmtlst:    stmtlst stmt |
;

stmt:       setStmt | if | print | unaryOperation | expr | returnStmt
;

getExpr:    '[' tGET ',' tIDENT ',' '[' exprList ']' ']'
        | '[' tGET ',' tIDENT ',' '[' ']' ']'
        | '[' tGET ',' tIDENT ']'
;

setStmt:    '[' tSET ',' tIDENT ',' expr ']'
;

if:     '[' tIF ',' condition ',' '[' stmtlst ']' ']'
        | '[' tIF ',' condition ',' '[' stmtlst ']' '[' stmtlst ']' ']'
;

print:      '[' tPRINT ',' expr ']'
;


operation:  '[' tADD ',' expr  ',' expr']' {
                                            $$ = SumExpr($4, $6);
                                            }
        | '[' tSUB ',' expr',' expr']'{
                                            $$ = SubExpr($4, $6);
                                            }
        | '[' tMUL ',' expr ',' expr ']'{
                                            $$ = MulExpr($4, $6);
                                            }
        | '[' tDIV ',' expr ',' expr  ']'{
                                            $$ = DivExpr($4, $6);
                                            }
;   


unaryOperation: '[' tINC ',' tIDENT ']'
        | '[' tDEC ',' tIDENT ']'
;

fulloperation: 
                operation stmt{printres($1);}|
                operation {$$ = $1;}
;


    

expr:       tNUMI {$$ = makeExpressionNodeFromInt($1);}
            | tNUMR {$$ = makeExpressionNodeFromReal($1);}
            | tSTRING {$$ = makeExpressionNodeFromStr($1);}
            | getExpr | function | fulloperation {$$ = $1;} | condition
;

function:    '[' tFUNCTION ',' '[' parametersList ']' ',' '[' stmtlst ']' ']'
        | '[' tFUNCTION ',' '[' ']' ',' '[' stmtlst ']' ']'
;

condition:  '[' tEQUALITY ',' expr ',' expr ']'
        | '[' tGT ',' expr ',' expr ']'
        | '[' tLT ',' expr ',' expr ']'
        | '[' tGEQ ',' expr ',' expr ']'
        | '[' tLEQ ',' expr ',' expr ']'
;

returnStmt: '[' tRETURN ',' expr ']'
        | '[' tRETURN ']'
;

parametersList: parametersList ',' tIDENT | tIDENT
;

exprList:   exprList ',' expr | expr
;
```

Comment: You seem to be at the big step from simply checking syntax to actually interpreting the source code. You have two choices really: 1) Calculate all results and return them in the parse semantic statements, like when you do `$$ = SumExpr($4, $6);` for `'[' tADD ',' expr  ',' expr']'`. You need to do that for *all* expressions and statements. Or 2) Create an intermediate representation of the source code, one that can be easier to interpret. For example some kind of stack-based low-level assembly-like code, or parse trees.

Comment: What tutorials or books are you reading? What classes are you taking? What examples have you been looking at and using for references? What do these resource say about interpreters and possible intermediate code generation?

Comment: I have designed a tree for holding all of the values and final value that I get is correct but I don't want to print the result for every expression, just the first one that calls it

Comment: I didn't say you should print the values, only that you calculate the result (or create nodes) that you return back up. Then if you do the interpretation while parsing, and do all the calculations inside the parser itself, then in the `stmtlst` you print the result of `stmt` (e.g. `printf("%d\n", $2)`). If you create a tree then in the `prog` rule you take the tree resulting from `stmtlist` and pass it to a function to print it.

Comment: For your language, which looks very lisp-like, I would just go for a tree, where each rule creates a node that it returns back up (e.g. `$$ = makeIfNode($3, $6, NULL)` for the single-branch `if` expression).

Comment: Thank you I managed to figure it out! 
What I did was to call printres function in the stmt rule when it sees an expression and that seems to work fine!
Thank you so much

Comment: Yes it is very much like Lisp, in fact it is called JISP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your language, which looks very lisp-like, I would go for a tree, where each rule creates a node that it returns back up.

For example for the single-branch `if` statement:

```
$$ = makeIfNode($3, $6, NULL)
```

For the nodes itself I would emulate C++-like inheritance using embedded nodes, where the top base-node contains a function pointer that is initialized to a pointer to evaluate the current node.

Like for example:

```
struct BaseNode
{
    int (*evaluate)(struct BaseNode *);
};
```

And for the `if` statement:

```
struct IfNode
{
    struct BaseNode base;
    struct BaseNode *condition;
    struct BaseNode *ifTrue;
    struct BaseNode *ifFalse;
};
```

The function to create the `if` statement node:

```
struct BaseNode *makeIfNode(struct BaseNode *condition, struct BaseNode *ifTrue, struct BaseNode *ifFalse)
{
    struct IfNode *ifNode = malloc(sizeof *ifNode);
    // TODO: Error checking

    ifNode->base.evaluate = &evaluateIfNode;
    ifNode->condition = condition;
    ifNode->ifTrue = ifTrue;
    ifNode->ifFalse = ifFalse;

    return (struct BaseNode *) ifNode;
}

static struct BaseNode *evaluateIfNode(struct BaseNode *base)
{
    struct IfNode *ifNode = (struct IfNode *) base;

    int result = evaluate(ifNode->condition);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        return evaluate(ifNode->ifTrue);
    }
    else if (ifNode->ifFalse != NULL)
    {
        return evaluate(ifNode->ifTrue);
    }
}
```

The global `evaluate` function takes the function pointer and calls it with the current node:

```
int evaluate(struct BaseNode *base)
{
    return base->evaluate(base);
}
```

Creates node structures, node creation functions and node evaluation functions similar to this for all your expressions and all your statements, and your top rule `prog` will simply call `printf("Result of program: %d\n", evaluate($2));` to run all the statements and all the expressions and print the final result.